# Add pulseaudio to Porteus kiosk 3.7.0 32 bit

Tags: linux, firefox, slackware

I try to add **pulseaudio-9.0-i586-1.xzm** and **firefox-56.0.1-i686-1.xzm** modules to **Porteus kiosk 3.7.0 32 bit**. I need pulseaudio package, because starting from version 52 Firefox only produce sound via pulseaudio.
When I try to run pulseaudio I get following error:

```
root@porteus-kiosk:~# pulseaudio
pulseaudio: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I try to use Porteus USM package manager to install **libssl.so.1**

I run

```
sudo -i usm -s libssl.so.1
```

and get:

```
Are you searching for a library file? 

libssl.so.1, it seems a library.
Would you like to find the package for it? [y/n]

libssl.so.1  was found in   firestorm-opensim-4.4.2.34167-i686-1_slonly.txz
```

Package **firestorm-opensim-4.4.2.34167-i686-1_slonly.txz** is very big (about 50 MB). When I try to inject it in Porteus kiosk - Porteus kiosk hangs on boot.

How to find package for **libssl.so.1**?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `openssl-solibs-1.0.2h-x86_64-1.txz`.You may need to `ln -s /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0` to some other path.